# Unable to compare string and int type column in LINQ + EntityFramework

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

I have two columns (Employee Id) and (UpdateBy). One column in string and another in integer. I want to use these two columns in join in LINQ query. Application is throwing error. My DB is MySQL. Please suggest solution for this.

```
I tried to convert using .ToString() or Int.Parse() but still throwing error.

var glPostingEntity1 = (from gl in msoft.glpostings
                         join emp in msoft.employeepersonals
                         on gl.UpdatedBy equals emp.EmployeeId
                         select gl).ToList();
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Amrapali

Comment: Did you tried `gl.UpdatedBy equals emp.EmployeeId.ToString()` ?

Comment: Sadly  EF < 6.1  does not know hot to`convert .ToString()` You must use embedded `function SqlFunctions.StringConvert`. Try converting one of them by using `SqlFunctions.StringConvert`. You can read it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466292.aspx) And  your EF >= 6.1 supports `ToString`

Comment: Why have both columns a different type if they store the same? I'd fix that instead.